# Jquery UI dialog does not appear. It says $(...).dialog is not a function

Tags: dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

http://ramin.azerizone.net/qiymet.html
Here is my demo webiste. In right side if I click red button, it says "dialog is not function". Although I have included jquery, and jquery ui. My script as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#order_services_button').on("click", function() {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        height : 320,
        width : 350,
        modal : true
    });

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are including two jQuery/jQueryUI files.
Remove the duplicate `script` tags and the dialog should work.

Comment: I removed duplicate script, still doesnt work. But, in this page dialog works. http://ramin.azerizone.net/
all scripts are the same.